# LiveUSB Black Screen on boot (Ryzen 5600G Biostar B450NH)

Tags: boot, graphics, live-usb, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I cannot manage to boot on live USB UEFI with Ryzen 5600G Graphics. I only can with Graphic Safe mode.
Even during safe mode, the screen keeps black after suspending ([and I need to suspend the system to securely wipe an SSD](https://code.mendhak.com/securely-wipe-ssd/)).

I seen post related to 5600G and RAM so I tried various config including auto, manual 3200MHz and lower frequencies as well, nothing made it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You state the video card but not the driver being used. Nor have you stated the version of Ubuntu and kernel. Please edit the question and add these 2 vital bits of info.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, no driver install since it's a live usb, so supposedly default ones. It's system is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)